# k-means clustering using Apache spark Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-analysis, apache-zeppelin

I have csv file with three column (string) and I have this code for clustering on Zeppelin

This is the code:

```
case class kmeansScore(k: String, score: String,j: String  )
val rawData = sc.textFile("/resources/data/v1.csv")
rawData.map(_.split(',').last).countByValue().toSeq.sortBy(_._2).reverse.foreach(println)

import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg._
val labelsAndData = rawData.zipWithIndex.flatMap {
  case (line,index) =>
    if (index == 0) {
      None
    } else {
      val buffer = line.split(',').toBuffer
      buffer.remove(1, 4)
      val label = buffer.remove(buffer.length-1)
      val vector = Vectors.dense(buffer.map(_.toDouble).toArray)
      Some((label,vector))
    }
}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering._   
def distance(a: Vector, b: Vector) = math.sqrt(a.toArray.zip(b.toArray).map(p => p._1 - p._2).map(d => d * d).sum)
def distToCentroid(datum: Vector, model: KMeansModel) = {
  val cluster = model.predict(datum)
  val centroid = model.clusterCenters(cluster)
  distance(centroid, datum)
}

import org.apache.spark.rdd._
val dataAsArray = labelsAndData.values.map(_.toArray).cache()
val dataAsArray.first().length
```

But I got this error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 90.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 90.0 (TID 138, localhost): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.remove(ArrayBuffer.scala:158)
```

What is the problem? I'm working on Zeppelin in https://my.datascientistworkbench.com/tools/zeppelin-notebook/

Comment: that link you provided requires a log in

Comment: @MattiLyra Yes I have an account on it, what is the point?

Comment: What is the utility of that link to anyone here who does not have an account there. Are we supposed to look at the notebook?

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to read stack traces. They will tell you *where* the error is. Without a proper stack trace, we can only speculate.

In particular, which *line* **in *your* code** does it fail?

My *blind* guess is that the last line is empty, and then the "remove" fails with this exception.

Your code looks fairly inefficient to me. I can only recommend to benchmark it with other tools, including non-spark tools. I know people love all the "functional" stuff like map and zip. But you'll be surprised by how slow this can be when doing numerical stuff.